# Name a variabile with the value of another variable

Tags: r

Suppose I have a variable:

```
x <- "Cat"
```

This variable x must define the name of another variable"

```
[x] <- c(1,2,3)
```

that is, in this example:

```
Cat <- c(1,2,3)
```

Any tip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here.

```
x <- "cat"

assign(x = x, value = 1:3)
```